# Alternate way to goto in js

Tags: javascript, npm

So, I'm working on a control panel with js, using npm. I'm currently at a loss for how to, for lack of a better term, reset half way through code. I'm trying to make it so when you enter a command, it goes back to the menu, without starting a new instance of it.

The code I have so far:

```
( async function main() {

  for (var d in dirs) {
    dir("parent", `${dirs[d]}`);
  }

  //Filler code to only be ran once.

   //Wanted Re-entry Point
  info(`Please Enter A Command!\nOr Enter 'Help'!`);

  var rep = await query(`\nCommand: `);
  rep = rep.toLowerCase();

  switch(rep) {
    case "help":

      var help = require("./Commands/Help.js");
      help.CmdList();
      //Go back to Re-Entry Point
      break;

    case "Start Server":
      //Menu stuff
      //Go to Re-Entry
      break;

    case "Stop Server":

      break;

    case "Create Server":

      break;

    case "Delete Server":

      break;

    default:
      warn("Unknown Command!!");
      break;
  }

})();
```

The thing is, I don't want it to restart at the beginning, because I'm going to eventually add things at the beginning I only want ran once. Besides modulizing it, how can I achieve this?

Comment: Make another function other than `main()` that looks like what you posted without the initialization code

Comment: Why not use [`EventEmitter`](https://nodejs.org/api/events.html#events_class_eventemitter) `pub/sub` is kinda `goto`

Answer (score 0):

You already provided the answer yourself: Use a named IIFE, then you can recall the function when needed:

```
  (function main() {
      const stay = "value";
      (function reentry() {
          const fresh = Math.random();
          console.log(stay, fresh);

          if(prompt("again?")) reentry();
      })();
  })();
```